# Rename multiple files in shell on Mac OS X

Tags: shell, rename

I have hundreds of the following files:

```
22170000000000002 Module 1 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv
22170000000000112 Module 2 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv
22180000000000002 Module 3 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv
```

How can I rename them using terminal with iOS system as

```
2217002_01_Item.csv
2217112_02_Item.csv
2218002_03_Item.csv
```

I know there a few threads on renaming files, but I am really new to shell commands. I need help with my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create test environnement:
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
echo "22170000000000002 Module 1 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv" > "22170000000000002 Module 1 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv"
echo "22170000000000112 Module 2 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv" > "22170000000000112 Module 2 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv"
echo "22180000000000002 Module 3 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv" > "22180000000000002 Module 3 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv"

# test file renaming:
f="22170000000000002 Module 1 Quiz Quiz Item Analysis Report.csv"
echo $f | sed -e "s/^\(....\)[0-9]*\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) .*Module \([0-9]\)* .*$/\1\2_0\3_Item.csv/g"
#return 2217002_01_Item.csv

# Verifing in loop 
ls -1 | while read f
do
  new_name=`echo $f | sed -e "s/^\(....\)[0-9]*\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) .*Module \([0-9]\)* .*$/\1\2_0\3_Item.csv/g"`
  echo "$f     ---->   $new_name"
done

# To rename all files : 
ls -1 | while read f
do
  new_name=`echo $f | sed -e "s/^\(....\)[0-9]*\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) .*Module \([0-9]\)* .*$/\1\2_0\3_Item.csv/g"`
  echo "$f     ---->   $new_name"
  mv "$f" "$new_name"     
done

ls -1
```

Comment: What does the -e in sed do? I read the man file of sed. But still do not understand. I removed the -e and it seems to give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the rename command :

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html